# Angular show-hide animation always shows with reusable field directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am working on implementing the 'Floating Label' concept. In trying to DRY up my code, I found a directive that will build up the input form HTML during the compile phase.

What is happening is that the 'Floating Label' is shown and then fades away when using the directive, but behaves properly by not having the label be shown at all in the hard-coded implementation.

Example Here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/GMZnAYlq49WoPhERRnEY?p=preview

The final HTML looks like below in both the hard-coded and directive implementation:

```
<div class="field">
  <label ng-show="ctrl.workingField" class="show-hide">Working Field</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="ctrl.workingField" placeholder="Working Field"/>
</div>
```

If the generated HTML is the same, why is the directive flashing the 'Floating Label'? I want to use the directive but have it behave like the hard-coded solution.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand that you want to meke decision using the directive or not? Because both two example work same.

The directive restricted for only element tag. It validate information and produce an html which is the same with your hard coded example. Namely, there is no other javascript action. Animations are worked via CSS.

You are not able to use the directive. Just use it's CSS. Hard coded example has more flexiable usage then the directive.

**Edit**
Sorry I have seen the problem that you say.

Please change the directive code line

```
 labelElement.attr('ng-show', attrs.ngModel);
```

to

```
labelElement.attr('ng-hide', !attrs.ngModel);
```

and add

```
.show-hide {
  display:none;
}
```

to css file.

Because ng-show try hide the label and it trigger ng-hide-add transition.